# Show Datatable after pressing a button

Tags: jsf, managed-bean

I want to show a datatable when I click a `commandButton`. My file looks like that:

```
<h:commandButton value="List all students"></h:commandButton>

<h:panelGroup id="table-wrapper">
    <h:dataTable value = "#{jSFDatabase.students}" var="s" border="1">

        <h:column><f:facet name = "header"><h:outputText value="ID"/></f:facet>
            <h:outputLabel value="#{s.id }"></h:outputLabel>
        </h:column>

         <h:column><f:facet name = "header"><h:outputText value="Firstname"/></f:facet>
            <h:outputLabel value="#{s.firstname }"></h:outputLabel>
         </h:column>   

         <h:column><f:facet name = "header"><h:outputText value="Lastname"/></f:facet>
            <h:outputLabel value="#{s.lastname }"></h:outputLabel>
         </h:column> 

         <h:column><f:facet name = "header"><h:outputText value="Birthdate"/></f:facet>
            <h:outputLabel value="#{s.birthdate }"></h:outputLabel>
         </h:column> 
    </h:dataTable>
</h:panelGroup>
```

How can I fix that issue? I tried to update the datatable but that didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

You can accomplish this using css.
Add a boolean flag in your managed bean, with a toggle method:

```
@ManagedBean
public class Mybean {
private boolean show = false;
public void toggle() {
    show= !show;
}

public boolean isShow() {
    return show;
}

public void setRender(boolean show) {
    this.show = show;
}
}
```

In your command button, call the toggle method, update the table and add the css style in your table to be visible or hidden according to the flag boolean.

```
<h:commandButton value="List all students" action="#{myBean.show}" update="table-wrapper"></h:commandButton>

<h:panelGroup id="table-wrapper" style="display: #{mybean.show ? 'none' : 'block'}">
...
</h:panelGroup>
```